# how to break long equations in cases latex?

Tags: equations, cases

I am trying to find a way to break long equations in a cases environment, I tried finding an answer to my question but no question was raised in this regards. Therefore, I decided to put it here.

I have the following equation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}

\begin{equation*}
    P_{t}^{h}= 
    \begin{cases}
            P_{t-1}^{h}  & \text{ if }A_{t}\leq \sum_{j=1}^{h-1}P_{t-1}^{j}(1+r_{g}) \\ 
            A_{t}-\sum_{j=1}^{h-1}P_{t-1}^{j}(1+r_{g}) &\text{ if } 
            \begin{split}
             & \sum_{j=1}^{h-1}P_{t-1}^{j}(1+r_{g})<A_{t} \\ 
             & \leq \sum_{j=1}^{h}P_{t-1}^{j}(1+r_{g}) \\
            \end{split} \\
            P_{t-1}^{h}(1+r_{g})  & \text{ if } \sum_{j=1}^{h}P_{t-1}^{j}(1+r_{g})<A_{t} \leq (P_{t-1}+C_{t-1})(1+r_{g})+B_{t-1} \\
            \begin{split}
                & P_{t-1}^{h}(1+r_{g})+\frac{P_{t-1}^{h}}{P_{t-1}}\alpha \delta  \\  & \quad \left(1-b\right)[A_{t}-(P_{t-1}+C_{t-1})(1+r_{g})-B_{t-1}]   
            \end{split}
            & \text{ if } (P_{t-1}+C_{t-1})(1+r_{g})+B_{t-1}<A_{t} \\
        \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Which prints out as so
[image]

Where as you can see this looks very bad. Can someone help me to sort things out?

Thank you in advance

Comment: try `aligned` instead of `split`, remember it takes an optional arg `[c|t|b]` that tells `aligned` how to vertically align, default is `c`. That being said, I'd probably rewrite this as it will probably never be readable in this form. BTW: please always post full minimal examples instead of just sniplets. That makes it easy for others to just copy your code and mess with it immediately.

Comment: @daleif thank you so much just did your recommendation.

Comment: @daleif tried aligned same problem stays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a decent way to split the last case, so I suggest a different way to set the display: the condition is added in the line below the formula, at 4em distance from the brace.

The first case is dealt with a box 4em wide, as the formula is too short.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\label{DonkelandEquation}
P_{t}^{h}= 
\begin{dcases}
\mathmakebox[4em][l]{P_{t-1}^{h}}
  \text{if }
  A_{t}\leq \sum_{j=1}^{h-1}P_{t-1}^{j}(1+r_{g})
\\[1ex]
A_{t}-\sum_{j=1}^{h-1}P_{t-1}^{j}(1+r_{g}) \\
  \qquad\qquad\text{if } 
    \sum_{j=1}^{h-1}P_{t-1}^{j}(1+r_{g})<A_{t}
    \leq \sum_{j=1}^{h}P_{t-1}^{j}(1+r_{g})
\\[1ex]
P_{t-1}^{h}(1+r_{g}) \\
  \qquad\qquad\text{if }
  \sum_{j=1}^{h}P_{t-1}^{j}(1+r_{g})<A_{t}
  \leq (P_{t-1}+C_{t-1})(1+r_{g})+B_{t-1}
\\[1ex]
P_{t-1}^{h}(1+r_{g})+\frac{P_{t-1}^{h}}{P_{t-1}}\alpha \delta
  (1-b)[A_{t}-(P_{t-1}+C_{t-1})(1+r_{g})-B_{t-1}] \\
  \qquad\qquad\text{if }
  (P_{t-1}+C_{t-1})(1+r_{g})+B_{t-1}<A_{t}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

With `dcases` everything is typeset in display style.

[image]